# Support of a convolution with the help of Titchmarsh theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have to use Titchmarsh theorem in order to prove that : 
if $f\in L^1[-1,1]$, and $supp(f*f*f*f-f*f)\subset [-1,1]$ then $supp(f)\subset[-1/4,1/4]$. Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $supp\, f\subset [a,b]$ and $supp\,g\subset [c,d]$ then $supp\, (f*g)\subset [a+c,b+d]$ and thus $supp\,(f*f)\subset [2a,2b]$ and $supp (f*f*f*f)\subset [4a,4b]$ and thus
$$
supp\,(f*f*f*f-f*f)\subset [\min(2a,4a), \max(2b, 4b) ].
$$

Comment: i understand, your answer is very clear but i have to prove that $supp(f)\subset[-1/4,1/4]$.

Comment: You get $-1\le 4a<0$ and $0<4b\le 1$ as necessary conditions…

Comment: So you mean that $min(2a,4a)=-1$ and $max(2b,4b)=1$ ? Sorry i do not know what to do after...

Comment: If $a<0<b$, then $\min(2a,4a)=4a$ and $\max(2b,4b)=4b$. If $a\ge 0$ then $2a\ge 0 >-1$ etc.

Comment: Do you mean that for example if $a<0<b$ then $supp(f*f*f*f-f*f)\subset [4a,4b]$ So if i take $a=-1/4 ,b=1/4$ then $supp(f)\subset[-1/4,1/4]$? Do you mean that if i have $supp(f*f*f*f-f*f)\subset...$ then i can conclude that $supp(f)\subset[-1/4,1/4]$ ? Because your proof is on the opposite direction...

Comment: See formula no. 1 and formula no. 5

Comment: Sorry what is formula 1 and formula no. 5 ?

Comment: Of the formulas in my answer.

Comment: So i have that IF 1. $supp(f)\subset [a,b]$ THEN 2. $ supp(f*f*f*f-f*f)\subset [4a,4b] $. But my problem is that i have to prove that IF 2. THEN 1.

Comment: No, you have to chose $a$ and $b$ in such a way that $-1\le 4a<0<4b\le 1$ in the least restrictive possibility. Which is trivial to do. Then in 2. the wanted conclusion is guaranteed.

Comment: So if i choose $a=-1/4$ ans $b=+1/4$ then i respect your inequalities. But i am really sorry i want to prove $2.\Rightarrow 1. $ and i think you are trying to prove $1. \Rightarrow 2.$ that is  your formula 1 $\Rightarrow$ formula 5 and i am trying to prove formula 5 $\Rightarrow$ formula 1. I am lost...

Comment: No, now from 1. $supp\,f\subset[-1/4,1/4]$ follows 2. $supp\,(f*f*f*f-f*f)\subset[-1,1]$ as requested.

Comment: So you settled everything (a and b) in order to have 2. $\Rightarrow$ 1. ?  I  am trying to write it correctly but i am a little bit puzzled. I do not know why i think there is a logical problem with your prove. Sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: i understand now! Really sorry. You proved a necessary condition and now i have to prove the sufficient condition by choosing $a$ and $b$ !